# Embed YouTube playlist/video using high-res image placeholder

Tags: youtube, embed

I am attempting to embed a YouTube video playlist using the following technique provided by YouTube itself:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLCAVPALzt27-IbMJ2bqRwGay9R1EEtC5X" frameborder="0" height="658" width="1170"></iframe>
```

YouTube allows us to upload an image placeholder but once embedded on our website, it creates an extremely low-res placeholder. Is there any sort of work-around for this? If I can't figure out then I'll probably just do a still image that *links* to YouTube itself. Once the video starts playing it's fine but we're trying to keep it clean if it's going into a slider/hero placeholder. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Something [like this](http://embed.plnkr.co/mklc7K8EBdSJ0JkM96IC/preview)?

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="video">
    <div class="video-box">
      <a class="thumbnail-link">
        <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi_webp/67OAp3FW6Dw/maxresdefault.webp" class="video-thumbnail">
        <iframe class="video-frame" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLCAVPALzt27-IbMJ2bqRwGay9R1EEtC5X&vq=hd720&showinfo=0&autohide=1&color=white&controls=2&modestbranding=1&theme=light" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
        </iframe>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

CSS code:

```
.video{
    margin-bottom:14px;
    width:1170px;
    height:658px;
}
.video-box{
    height:925px;
    width:1646px;
    position:relative;
}

.video-thumbnail{
    z-index:300;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
}

.video-frame{
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
}

.thumbnail-link .video-thumbnail{
    display:block;
}

.thumbnail-link:hover .video-thumbnail{
    display:none;
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mklc7K8EBdSJ0JkM96IC)

You can always get the high res thumbnail image by adding `maxresdefault.webp` at the end of your URL. [Example](http://i.ytimg.com/vi_webp/67OAp3FW6Dw/maxresdefault.webp):

```
http://i.ytimg.com/vi_webp/67OAp3FW6Dw/maxresdefault.webp
```

Comment: webp didn't work for me ([example](http://i.ytimg.com/vi/buM6MtU-DZg/maxresdefault.webp)), but jpg did ([example](http://i.ytimg.com/vi/buM6MtU-DZg/maxresdefault.jpg)).

Answer (score 3):

Each YouTube video has 4 generated images. They are predictably formatted as follows:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/0.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/1.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/2.jpg
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/3.jpg
```

The first one in the list is a full size image and others are thumbnail images. The default thumbnail image (ie. one of `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, `3.jpg`) is:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/default.jpg
```

For the high quality version of the thumbnail use a url similar to this:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/hqdefault.jpg
```

There is also a medium quality version of the thumbnail, using a url similar to the HQ:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/mqdefault.jpg
```

For the standard definition version of the thumbnail, use a url similar to this:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/sddefault.jpg
```

For the maximum resolution version of the thumbnail use a url similar to this:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/maxresdefault.jpg
```

All of the above urls are available over https too. Just change `http` to `https` in any of the above urls. Additionally, the slightly shorter hostname `i3.ytimg.com` works in place of `img.youtube.com` in the example urls above.

```
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/Q1wb1lS09Sg/maxresdefault.jpg">
```

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/norcaljohnny/phwzLL5m/)

Answer (score 2):

Google brought me here when I was looking for help to the same blurry thumbnail problem. I found this great solution:

Simply replace the old embed playlist spell...

```
/embed/videoseries?list=
```

...with this:

```
/embed&listType=playlist&list=
```

...and you get a HD quality placeholder to your embedded playlist player!

Additional spells (such as &rel=0&showinfo=1&modestbranding=1 etc.) explained at: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters